# How to read a multiple field of JSON file using a chainlink oracle

Tags: solidity, chainlink

**chainlink**
I've altered the chainlink large Response example to read a JSON file that contains multiple data that I wish to bring into and store in the smart contract

//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

import '@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/ChainlinkClient.sol';
import '@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/ConfirmedOwner.sol';

/**

- Request testnet LINK and ETH here: https://faucets.chain.link/
- Find information on LINK Token Contracts and get the latest ETH and LINK faucets here: https://docs.chain.link/docs/link-token-contracts/
  */

contract GenericLargeResponse is ChainlinkClient, ConfirmedOwner {
using Chainlink for Chainlink.Request;

```
// variable bytes(arbitrary-length raw byte data) returned in a single oracle 
response
bytes public data;
bytes public imgdata;
string public image;
string public name;

bytes32 private jobId;
uint256 private fee;

/**
 * @notice Initialize the link token and target oracle
 * @dev The oracle address must be an Operator contract for multiword response
 *
 *
 * Rinkeby Testnet details:
 * Link Token: 0x01BE23585060835E02B77ef475b0Cc51aA1e0709
 * Oracle: 0xf3FBB7f3391F62C8fe53f89B41dFC8159EE9653f (Chainlink DevRel)
 * jobId: 7da2702f37fd48e5b1b9a5715e3509b6
 *
 */
constructor() ConfirmedOwner(msg.sender) {
    setChainlinkToken(0x01BE23585060835E02B77ef475b0Cc51aA1e0709);
    setChainlinkOracle(0xf3FBB7f3391F62C8fe53f89B41dFC8159EE9653f);
    jobId = '7da2702f37fd48e5b1b9a5715e3509b6';
    fee = (1 * LINK_DIVISIBILITY) / 10; // 0,1 * 10**18 (Varies by network and job)
}

/**
 * @notice Request variable bytes from the oracle
 */
function requestBytes() public {
    Chainlink.Request memory req = buildChainlinkRequest(jobId, address(this), 
    this.fulfillBytes.selector);
    req.add(
        'get', 
        'https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmWBxuuuqDxjiSvHsf52bQVkQ7Sqv1dLx4DJPFZ4KdsHGZ/1.json'
    );
    req.add('path', 'name');
    req.add('path', 'image');
    sendChainlinkRequest(req, fee);
}

event RequestFulfilled(bytes32 indexed requestId, bytes indexed data, bytes indexed 
imgdata);

/**
 * @notice Fulfillment function for variable bytes
 * @dev This is called by the oracle. recordChainlinkFulfillment must be used.
 */
function fulfillBytes(bytes32 requestId, bytes memory bytesData, bytes memory 
    imgdata_) public recordChainlinkFulfillment(requestId) {
    emit RequestFulfilled(requestId, bytesData, imgdata_);
    data = bytesData;
    name = string(data);
    imgdata = imgdata_;
    image = string(imgdata);
}

/**
 * Allow withdraw of Link tokens from the contract
 */
function withdrawLink() public onlyOwner {
    LinkTokenInterface link = LinkTokenInterface(chainlinkTokenAddress());
    require(link.transfer(msg.sender, link.balanceOf(address(this))), 'Unable to 
    transfer');
}
```

}

This is the data its trying to read:
{"name":"Token #1","description":"Ful player NFT #1","image":"ipfs//QmetFE2HRTFMkz5WamY8aw2hCDf7BJjXQPWv3et1bVqtER/1.jpg"}

Answer (score 1):

In general your approach in your contract is adequate, but I would make the small change to match a job-spec a node operator would need to add to their node to service your requests.

```
req.add('path1', 'name');
req.add('path2', 'image');
```

In general, if you have two different paths, but have them assigned to the same variable, the request will error out.

Finally, your request type `(get > x2 bytes)` is a non-standard job request. You would have to find a node operator to host the associated job-spec on their node/oracle for your smart contract to work as intended.

If you want I can host this job on our node if you like, you can message me on our discord server: https://discord.gg/PgxRVrDUm7